# CK Editor strips allowed attributes with source feature

Tags: ckeditor

I have `class` on `table` elements as `allowedContent` and table border, cellpadding and cellspacing as `disallowedContent`. The class stays when saving, but gets stripped if I go to the visual side, then back to the source.

I've seen `extraAllowedContent` mentioned but I'm not sure what it's for and it doesn't solve the (wrongful) sanitization that happens when switching (back) to source.

**Update:** I've throughly ensured table class is an allowed attribute and added the classes I want available. I can save or cancel as many times as I want - as long as I'm coming back to source, the class persists. I inspected the table class when source had been toggled off, and it had `class="cke_show_border"`. I believe adding that class may be the issue. The `class` attribute is also being stripped from other elements (h1 for example), so it's not a table plugin or sanitize issue. CKEditor itself seems to think it has domain over class attributes.